# How prove this $n|a$ if $S_{m}-S_{k-1}=\dfrac{a}{b}$

Tags: number-theory

let $$\dfrac{a_{1}}{b_{1}},\dfrac{a_{2}}{b_{2}},\cdots,\dfrac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}$$ be Rational number,and such
$$\gcd(n,\prod_{i=1}^{n}b_{i})=1$$define
$$S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_{i}}{b_{i}}=\dfrac{a}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}}$$
show that

there exsit  integer  $k$ and $m$,$(1\le k\le m\le n)$,then
$$S_{m}-S_{k-1}=\dfrac{a}{b}$$
and such $n|a$

My try: since
$$s_{m}-s_{k-1}=\sum_{i=k}^{m}\dfrac{a_{i}}{b_{i}}=\dfrac{a}{\prod_{i=k}^{m}b_{i}}$$
then How prove $n|a?$

and I know this famous problem (IMO1979)
if
$$\dfrac{p}{q}=1-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{4}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{1319}$$
then
$$1979|p$$
poof: note
$$1-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{4}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{1319}=H_{1319}-2H_{2\times 659}=H_{1319}-H_{659}$$
where
$$H_{n}=1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n}$$
since
\begin{align*}H_{1319}-H_{659}&=\left(\dfrac{1}{660}+\dfrac{1}{1319}\right)+\left(\dfrac{1}{661}+\dfrac{1}{1318}\right)+\cdots+\left(\dfrac{1}{989}+\dfrac{1}{990}\right)\\
&=1979\times\left(\dfrac{1}{660\times 1319}+\dfrac{1}{661\times 1318}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{989\times 990}\right)
\end{align*}
By Done!

But my problem ,I can't ,Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z=\lbrace 1,2,3,\ldots ,n-1 \rbrace$. There are $n-1$ elements
in $Z$. For each $k$, there is an integer $z_k \in Z$ such that
$S_k \equiv z_k \ ({\sf mod}\ n)$.

By the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle),
there must be two indices $i < j$ with
$S_i \equiv S_j \ ({\sf mod}\ n)$. Then

$$
S_j-S_i=\frac{a}{b}, \ \text{with } n|a
$$

Comment: Hell,what are you $S?$

Comment: @math110 Sorry, I meant $Z$.